# Can I use ORM without connecting entity to a database table

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have an Entity that pulls it's data from a REST web service. To keep thing consistent with the entities in my app that pull data from the database I have used ORM and overridden the find functions in the repository.

My problem is that ORM seems to demand a database table. When I run `doctrine:schema:update` it moans about needing an index for the entity then when I add one it creates me a table for the entity. I guess this will be a problem in the future as ORM will want to query the database and not the web service.

So... am I doing this wrong?

1, If I continue to use ORM how can I get it to stop needing the database table for a single entity.

2, If I forget ORM where do I put my data loading functions? Can I connect the entity to a repository without using ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So... am I doing this wrong?

**Yes.** It doesn't make sense to use the ORM interfaces if you don't really want to use an ORM.

I think the best approach is NOT to think about implementation details at all. Introduce your own interfaces for repositories:

```php
interface Products
{
    /**
     * @param string $slug
     *
     * @return Product[]
     */
    public function findBySlug($slug);
}

interface Orders
{
    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * 
     * @return Order[]
     */
    public function findProductOrders(Product $product);
}
```

And implement them with either an ORM:

```php
class DoctrineProducts implements Products
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function findBySlug($slug)
    {
        return $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
           ->select()
           // ...
    }
}
```

or a Rest client:

```php
class RestOrders implements Orders
{
    private $httpClient;

    public function __construct(HttpClient $httpClient)
    {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
    }

    public function findProductOrders(Product $product)
    {
        $orders = $this->httpClient->get(sprintf('/product/%d/orders', $product->getId()));

        $orders = $this->hydrateResponseToOrdersInSomeWay($orders);

        return $orders;
    }
}
```

You can even make some methods use the http client and some use the database in a single repository.

Register your repositories as services and use them rather then calling `Doctrine::getRepository()` directly:

```
services:
    repository.orders:
        class: DoctrineOrders
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

Always rely on your repository interfaces and never on a specific implementation. In other words, always use a repository interface type hint:

```php
class DefaultController
{
    private $orders;

    public function __construct(Orders $orders)
    {
        $this->orders = $orders;
    }

    public function indexAction(Product $product)
    {
        $orders = $this->orders->findProductOrders($product);

        // ...
    }
}
```

If you don't register controllers as services:

```php
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Product $product)
    {
        $orders = $this->get('repository.orders')->findProductOrders($product);

        // ...
    }
}
```

A huge advantage of this approach is that you can always change the implementation details later on. Mysql is not good enough for search anymore? Let's use elastic search, it's only a single repository!

If you need to call $product->getOrders() and fetch orders from the API behind the scenes it should still be possible with some help of doctrine's lazy loading and event listeners.

Comment: So working MVC, the RestOrders and DoctrineProducts classes are repositories the same as I've already written to overwrite the ORM functions. I just need to include and create them as needed rather than using the $em->getRepository() function to load them. The Order entity doesn't need to know it is being managed by the RestOrders repository. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, register your repositories as services and use them instead of Doctrine::getRepository(). You can still extend doctrine's entity repository base class if you want, in which case you'll need to register them to be created by a factory (doctrine will be a factory). Or you can do what I presented in the answer and only inject the entity manager into your repo.